# Is it possible to count() a subset of a distinct query?

Tags: mysql

I have a small mysql table I'm trying to count distinct rows that fall in a certain date span. Let me clarify what I'm asking before I get too far, because this sounds simple.

Here's the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `family_awards` (
`award_id` bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`family_id` bigint(50) NOT NULL,
`serviceCode` int(3) NOT NULL,`date_received` date NOT NULL,
`created_in` varchar(40) NOT NULL,`created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_by` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`award_id`)
)
```

A family_id can receive upto 4 awards (award_id) per year, 1 per quarter max.

Now, here's the number I need to provide to the boss.
The distinct (counted rows) number of family_id that have received an award between 10-1-13 & 12-31-13, that have not previously received an award.

I need to be able to show how many family_ids received a benefit for the FIRST time this year, within the queried quarter.

For example:

```
AWARD_ID.   FAMILY_ID.   DATE_REC.
1           5            1/15/13
2           7            4/27/13
3           2            6/22/13
4           6            7/28/13
5           5            10/27/13
6           9            11/14/13
```

Quarter 1 (Jan -Mar) would have 1 new, distinct family_id seeing as how the year just started.
... Qtr 2
... Qtr 3
Quarter 4 (Oct - Dec) should only count 1, since family_id 5 had already received an award in Jan.

How can I do this in a query?
tyvm

EDIT (from comment):

This is the query I'm testing:

```
SELECT distinct(family_id)
FROM family_awards`
WHERE family_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct(family_id)
                        FROM family_awards
                        WHERE date_received > '2013-01-01' AND date_received <= '2013-09-30'
                       ) AND
     ( date_received >= '2013-10-01' AND date_received <= '2013-12-31' )
```

Comment: This is the query I'm testing:  `SELECT distinct(family_id) FROM `family_awards` WHERE family_id NOT IN ( SELECT distinct(family_id) FROM family_awards WHERE date_received > '2013-01-01' AND date_received <= '2013-09-30' ) AND ( date_received >= '2013-10-01' AND date_received <= '2013-12-31' )`

Comment: . . That should be edited into the question, rather than being in a comment.  (I've already done this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the "first" is to use `min` on the date

```
SELECT family_id, min(date_rec) as firstdate
FROM family_awards`
group by family_id;
```

Now, if you want the first in a quarter, use this as a subquery:

```
select year(firstdate) as y, quarter(firstdate) as q, count(*) as NumFirsts
from (SELECT family_id, min(date_rec) as firstdate
      FROM family_awards`
      group by family_id
     ) fa
group by year(firstdate), quarter(firstdate);
```

EDIT:

You want to count familys "that have not previously received an award".  Another way of saying this is that the first reward is in the quarter.  So, this approach finds the date of the first award for each family and then uses that for the count.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't entirely understand the logic in your answer Gordon. Would you mind a brief explanation? Also, will this query hold true if it were a fiscal year instead of  a calendar year? ( I know that wasn't part of the original question, just curious)

Comment: Gordon. I have this theory that you're some kind of bot. Your answers are just too fast and thorough! Please slow down and restore some credibility! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT IN` clause you are  using is excluding families that have received an award in the time frame you want. Try changing the `NOT IN` clause to exclude those outside the period:

```
SELECT distinct(family_id) 
FROM family_awards` 
WHERE family_id NOT IN ( 
        SELECT family_id
        FROM family_awards 
        WHERE date_received < '2013-09-30') 
    AND ( date_received >= '2013-09-30' AND date_received <= '2013-12-31' )`
```

Comment: If a family received a benefit in quarter 1,2 or 3 - then I don't want them in the count for quarter 4. Although in your example, the sun query is getting a list of family ids from anything before the year in question. I don't see that getting the number I'm trying to reach. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user2977468 Typo on my part. The above will select families that have not receive an award before `2013-09-30` but have received an award between `2013-09-30` and `2013-12-31`.

Comment: @user2977468 Ah my aplogies. Misunderstood what you need. To confirm: The output you want is a count of new award winning families per quarter?